# how to allow other users access to my email from google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

when I am logged into my gmail account I can access my emails from an app script in a google sheet table with

```
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(folder).getThreads();
```

but I would like this script to work for other users of the board, i.e. they access my gmail account to read, write or delete emails.
This is for collecting data from emails and inserting it into the table.

Comment: Allowing other users to access your Gmail mailbox is a simple thing as using a simple parameter. You could achieve this by calling the Gmail API (not the same as the Google Apps Script GmailApp service) by passing the appropriate toke by using the UrlFetchApp service). If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `they access my gmail account`? Is this something that is already happening or is it something you want to accomplish? Also, can you clarify `I would like this script to work for other users of the board`? You want them to execute this script while logged with their own accounts? How is the script getting executed (manually from the editor, through some trigger, etc.)? And what's stopping those other users from executing this?

Comment: ok, I have a trigger that will daily look for an email in my mailbox to update my table
and I would like to give this possibility to do it manually at any time by the users of the table via a menu. This means that from their gmail account they have permission to read and delete this email in my account and that the script points to my mailbox to extract it.
I searched on the gmail api side and couldn't find a clear tutorial.
The javascript speaks of python.

Comment: escuse, it is google transalte english (i'm french)

Comment: What kind of trigger do you have? Consider providing more parts of your code so that your situation is clarified. Also, when you say `from their gmail account they have permission to read and delete this email in my account and that the script points to my mailbox to extract it` you are stating a goal, and not the current behavior, right? Take a look at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350. Also, are the other users part of your same organization?

Comment: Consider providing more parts of your code so your situation is clear.
function MAJTableauxLR() {
    var dossier = "INBOX/MAJTableauxLR";
    var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(dossier).getThreads();
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var ws = ss.getSheets()[0];
    for (var j = threads.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        var message = threads[j].getMessages();
        var body = message[0].getPlainBody();
the rest is integrating the data into the table

Comment: What type of trigger do you have?
> a daily trigger at a fixed time
Also, when you say from their gmail account that they have permission to read and delete this email in my account and the script points to my mailbox to extract it, you are indicating a purpose, and no current behavior, right?
>yes that is the goal.
See support.google.com/mail/answer/138350.
>I added a delegate account, but the script does not work from the delegate account.
Also, are the other users part of your same organization?
>yes from the same organization but we don't have access to google groups.

Comment: Hi, since this is a time-trigger, it will run under the account of the person who created it. So, if you installed it, it will run as you. In that case, I don't understand your goal of letting others access your inbox through this; the function will access the inbox of the person who installed the trigger. Can you clarify this?

Comment: of course it already works.
But my request is because users must also be able to trigger this type of script at any time to do an instant update

Comment: In that case, deploy the script as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=en) that runs as yourself but to which the other users have access.  Therefore, whenever users need to execute this script, they'd just call the web app URL. Do you think this would be a valid workaround for you?